# Как задать условие выполнение для триггера (ЕСЛИ, ТО)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер, concat

Имеется таблица, примерно, такого содержания:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Actavia] (
        [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [ItemIndex] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
        [ItemType] NVARCHAR (max) NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Actavia] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
    );
GO
```

Также имеется триггер который вносит запись в столбец [ItemIndex]

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
ON dbo.Actavia
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE Actavia
SET [ItemIndex]= CONCAT(format(Id, '0000'), 'loremipsum'), 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id from inserted)
```

Вопрос: как реализовать действие при котором, в случае, если столбец [ItemType] содержит, например, запись "Eq" будет выполнятся

```
[ItemIndex]= CONCAT(format(Id, '0000'), 'loremipsum')
```

а если [ItemType] содержит запись "P", то

```
[ItemIndex]= CONCAT(format(Id, '0000'), 'dolorsitamet')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это только два возможных значения для столбца [ItemType], тогда IIF(...)

В противном случае, когда несколько значений, `CASE` выражение.

**SQL**

```
SET [ItemIndex]= CONCAT(format(Id, '0000'), IIF([ItemType]='Eq', 'loremipsum','dolorsitamet')),
```